# java - Is it possible to check current used heap space at runtime?

Tags: java, apache-poi, heap-memory

I'm writing an app the generates a big xlsx file using apache-POI.
At a certain time I get OutOfHeapSpace exception.

I want to  solve it by writing the content to the xlsx file when I determine that I'll soon be out of space, and thus freeing the memory, and then reading the file from the disk and continuing the writing.

A better solution might be to predefine the number of cells I'll write in each "block" , and then write the block to disk, but in any case this made me wonder if there is a way to determine the heap space that is left at runtime?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/GetHeapSize.html

Comment: yes it does with the question regarding heap space. bunting solved the greated issue.
thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freeing unused memory at runtime is probably not very reliable since the JVM has considerable freedom in deciding when to garbage collect.

POI recently [introduced the SXSSF API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) that uses streaming and thereby significantly reduces memory footprint for writing spreadsheets. This should help even with very big xsls files. There are a couple of downsides which are shown [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/). But if you can live with them, this should alleviate you of heap related problems.

Answer (score 3):

The [MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) can give you a fair amount of information about the current memory usage.

```
public class PrintMemory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MemoryMXBean memoryMXBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
        long[] array;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            array = new long[100000];
            System.out.printf("%d%n", memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the available memory, but it only tells you the most you can allocate without triggering a GC.

Instead you can trigger a GC and see how much memory is free after wards.  The problem this is it has a perform overhead.

Another option is to monitor the GC cleanups via JMX and see how much is free after it naturally triggers a GC (if it doesn't run, you don't have a problem)

Answer (score 1):

Using one of the coming with the JVM JMX MBeans is worth considering.
Like this one [MemoryPoolMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html)